# kill a process without raising error with qt

Tags: qt

I need to kill a process without raising any errors. I need to make distinction between when the process crashed and when the user killed it intentionally. I see that on Windows a command line process can be closed only using .kill() and not .terminate().

If I connect the .errorOccurred(), the function is called even if I intentionally press the button to kill the process. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

There is [QObject::blockSignals()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals), which temporarily prevents any signal from being emitted.
However, I would avoid using it, and handle it instead in the code that is handling the process.

Two options:

1. Disconnect the process’ signals before terminating:

   ```
   m_process.disconnect(this);
   m_process.kill();
   ```
2. Remember that you’re in “killing state” and ignore the signal/handle it differently:

   ```
   m_killingProcess = true; // member variable defaulting to false
   m_process.kill();
   ```

   In the slot connected to `errorOccurred`:

   ```
   void Foo::processErrorOccurred(QProcess::ProcessError error)
   {
       if (m_killingProcess) {
           // do nothing?
           return;
       }

       // handle process error (when not killing)
   }
   ```